# Why is my inject method not working? It seems to be constructed correctly

Tags: ruby

I have an array of hashes representing days of recorded weather information.

```
data = [
    {"temp": "22", "rain": "0.5"},
    {"temp": "30", "rain": "1.5"},
    {"temp": "40", "rain": "2.8"}
}
```

I want to get the total rainfall for all days. So I write

```
puts data.inject{|rain, day| rain + day['rain'].to_f}
```

But I get back the error `undefined method [] for nil`.

What have I done wrong?

Comment: The literal you posted (`data`) isn't syntactically valid, please fix it so people can copy and paste it to test your code.

Comment: JSON is not a native Ruby data structure.

Comment: With your last *edit*, you should get **different** error. Please update with actual error.

Comment: With the code you posted, you shouldn't get a `NoMethodError`, you should get a `SyntaxError`. Your code and your error message do not match. Please make sure that you post a minimal example which demonstrates your problem, the error message you are getting, describe the steps you took to solve your problem and where you got stuck, the problem you are trying to solve, and why you are solving it in that specific way, what you expect to happen, what actually happens etc.

Answer (score 2):

Use `0` as the initial argument.

```
puts data.inject(0) { |rain, day| rain + day['rain'].to_f }
```

Now, `rain` will be initialized with `0` in the first iteration and `day` to the `Hash` objects of the `data` array. Now from the *second* iteration on-wards, each time `rain` will hold the result of `rain + day['rain'].to_f`, and `day` to the next `Hash` element. Read the official documentation of [`#inject`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject).

> If you specify a block, then for each element in enum the block is passed an accumulator value (memo) and the element. If you specify a symbol instead, then each element in the collection will be passed to the named method of memo. In either case, the result becomes the new value for memo. At the end of the iteration, the final value of memo is the return value for the method.
>
> *If you do not explicitly specify an initial value for memo*, then the first element of collection is used as the initial value of memo.

Answer (score 1):

`inject` with a block but without initial memo argument initializes memo (`rain` in your case) to `nil`. Nil cannot be added to (`nil + 2 #!bang`). Also, you do not close the data array correctly (with a `]`). With following code it should work.

```
data = [
    {"temp" => "22", "rain" => "0.5"},
    {"temp" => "30", "rain" => "1.5"},
    {"temp" => "40", "rain" => "2.8"}
]
puts data.inject(0){|rain, day| rain + day['rain'].to_f} # => 4.8
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to be sure your data is exist. In that case

1. Fix curly bracket
2. It's better to make Hash keys as **symbols**, but **not strings**. For string key you must use `'key' => 'value'` syntax.

So you should change this:

```
data = [
    {"temp": "22", "rain": "0.5"},
    {"temp": "30", "rain": "1.5"},
    {"temp": "40", "rain": "2.8"}
]
```

To this. Here is output of IRB:

```
?> data = [
?>     {temp: "22", rain: "0.5"},
?>     {temp: "30", rain: "1.5"},
?>     {temp: "40", rain: "2.8"}
>> ]
=> [{:temp=>"22", :rain=>"0.5"}, {:temp=>"30", :rain=>"1.5"}, {:temp=>"40", :rain=>"2.8"}]
```

**You've got `Array` of `Hashes`.**

Next is `map` function:

```
puts data.map {|rain, day| rain + day['rain'].to_f}
```

This is wrong. You should refer each **element of Array** one by one:

```
puts data.map {|i| puts i[:temp] + ' ' + i[:rain] }
```

Here is `i` variable which refers to **each element of Array**. Each element is the `Hash` with `:temp` and `:rain` keys.

Now you can sum up with `inject(0)`:

```
puts data.inject(0){|rain, day| rain + day[:rain].to_f}
```

Try it out! Good luck!